# javascript find deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to filter objects recursively in a deeply nested array of objects using javascript, maybe with the help of lodash. 
What is the cleanest way to do it, If I don't know how many nested object there will be in my array?

Let's say I have the following structure

```
[
  {
    label: "first",
    id: 1,
    children: []
  },
  {
    label: "second",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        label: "third",
        id: 3,
        children: [
          {
            label: "fifth",
            id: 5,
            children: []
          },
          {
            label: "sixth",
            id: 6,
            children: [
              {
                label: "seventh",
                id: 7,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "fourth",
        id: 4,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to find the one with `id 6`, and if it has children return true otherwise false.

Of course If I have a similar data structure but with different number of items it should work too.

Comment: You can write a function that can iterate over the top-level items, and then modify that function to accept an input array to iterate over, and then have that function call itself recursively for each item's `children`.

Comment: are any of the children refs to parents? that can cause an infinite loop when iterating. otherwise, it's a pretty straight-forward for/in, recursively calling if the typeof all[specific] =='object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you only want a `true` of `false` answer you can use `some()` on the recursion, effectively doing a depth-first search, and make it pretty succinct:

```js
let arr = [{label: "first",id: 1,children: []},{label: "second",id: 2,children: [{label: "third",id: 3,children: [{label: "fifth",id: 5,children: []},{label: "sixth",id: 6,children: [{label: "seventh",id: 7,children: []}]}]},{label: "fourth",id: 4,children: []}]}];

function findNested(arr, id) {
    let found = arr.find(node => node.id === id)
    return found 
      ? found.children.length > 0 
      : arr.some((c) => findNested(c.children, id))

} 

console.log(findNested(arr, 6))  // True: found with children
console.log(findNested(arr, 7))  // False: found no children
console.log(findNested(arr, 97)) // False: not found
```

Comment: I think that instead of `(found &&  ...) ||` it would be more logical to do `found ? ... :` since if the element was found if makes no sense to still execute `arr.some` if the found node has no children.

Comment: @trincot `||` has short-circuiting behavior so it doesn't execute the `arr.some()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think he means for the case where `found` exists but has no children. Doesn't make sense to do DFS after that. Having said that, nice solution :)

Comment: As slider said ^^^^  *"...if the found node has no children"*

Comment: I decided to go with your solution, and it works flawlessly without any issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a recursive solution along the lines of this might work for you? Here, the node with supplied id is recursively searched for through the 'children' of the supplied input data. If a child node with matching id is found, a boolean result is returned based on the existence of data in that nodes `children` array:

```js
function nodeWithIdHasChildren(children, id) {
  
  for(const child of children) {

    // If this child node matches supplied id, then check to see if
    // it has data in it's children array and return true/false accordinly
    if(child.id === id) {
    
      if(Array.isArray(child.children) && child.children.length > 0) {
        return true
      }
      else {
        return false
      }
    }
    else {
    
      const result = nodeWithIdHasChildren(child.children, id);

      // If result returned from this recursion branch is not undefined
      // then assume it's true or false from a node matching the supplied
      // id. Pass the return result up the call stack
      if(result !== undefined) {
        return result
      }
    }
  }  
}

const data = [
  {
    label: "first",
    id: 1,
    children: []
  },
  {
    label: "second",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        label: "third",
        id: 3,
        children: [
          {
            label: "fifth",
            id: 5,
            children: []
          },
          {
            label: "sixth",
            id: 6,
            children: [
              {
                label: "seventh",
                id: 7,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "fourth",
        id: 4,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];



console.log('node 6 has children:', nodeWithIdHasChildren( data, 6 ) )

console.log('node 7 has children:', nodeWithIdHasChildren( data, 7 ) )

console.log('node 100 has children:', nodeWithIdHasChildren( data, 7 ), '(because node 100 does not exist)' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `recursion` and doing it via only one `Array.find`:

```js
const data = [ { label: "first", id: 1, children: [] }, { label: "second", id: 2, children: [ { label: "third", id: 3, children: [ { label: "fifth", id: 5, children: [] }, { label: "sixth", id: 6, children: [ { label: "seventh", id: 7, children: [] } ] } ] }, { label: "fourth", id: 4, children: [] } ] } ];

const search = (data, id) => {
  var f, s = (d, id) => d.find(x => x.id == id ? f = x : s(x.children, id)) 
  s(data, id)
  return f ? f.children.length > 0 : false
}

console.log(search(data, 6))  // True: found with children
console.log(search(data, 7))  // False: found but has no children
console.log(search(data, 15)) // False: not found at all
```

The idea is to have a recursive function which when finds the id remembers the object.

Once we have the found (or we know we do not have an entry found) just return the children `array length` or return `false`.

If you want to actually return the `found object` instead of the boolean for `children.length`:

```js
const data = [ { label: "first", id: 1, children: [] }, { label: "second", id: 2, children: [ { label: "third", id: 3, children: [ { label: "fifth", id: 5, children: [] }, { label: "sixth", id: 6, children: [ { label: "seventh", id: 7, children: [] } ] } ] }, { label: "fourth", id: 4, children: [] } ] } ];

const search = (data, id) => {
  var f, s = (d, id) => d.find(x => x.id == id ? f = x : s(x.children, id)) 
  s(data, id)
  return f
}

console.log(search(data, 6))  // returns only the object with id:6
console.log(search(data, 7))  // returns only the object with id: 7
console.log(search(data, 71)) // returns undefined since nothing was found
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) or the [`JSON.stringify` replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) can be used to check all values, and generate flat id lookup object with references to the nodes :

```js
var lookup = {}, json = '[{"label":"first","id":1,"children":[]},{"label":"second","id":2,"children":[{"label":"third","id":3,"children":[{"label":"fifth","id":5,"children":[]},{"label":"sixth","id":6,"children":[{"label":"seventh","id":7,"children":[]}]}]},{"label":"fourth","id":4,"children":[]}]}]'

var result = JSON.parse(json, (key, val) => val.id ? lookup[val.id] = val : val);

console.log( 'id: 2, children count:', lookup[2].children.length )
console.log( 'id: 6, children count:', lookup[6].children.length )
console.log( lookup )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `deepdash` extension for `lodash`:

```
var id6HasChildren = _.filterDeep(obj,
  function(value, key, parent) {
    if (key == 'children' && parent.id == 6 && value.length) return true;
  },
  { leavesOnly: false }
).length>0;
```

Here is a [docs for filterDeep](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep).

And this a [full test](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/blob/bc30f79199cd6d774e8d358348a237fc30f39b2f/test/stackoverflow.js#L221) for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "recursion" like below to check if `id` has children or not

```js
let arr = [{label: "first",id: 1,children: []},{label: "second",id: 2,children: [{label: "third",id: 3,children: [{label: "fifth",id: 5,children: []},{label: "sixth",id: 6,children: [{label: "seventh",id: 7,children: []}]}]},{label: "fourth",id: 4,children: []}]}];

function hasChildren(arr, id) {
  let res = false
  for (let d of arr) {
    if(d.id == id) return d.children.length > 0
    res = res || hasChildren(d.children, id)
    if(res) return true
  }
  return res
}

console.log('id 4 has children? ', hasChildren(arr, 4))
console.log('id 6 has children? ', hasChildren(arr, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using three simple javascript functions:

```
// Function to Flatten results
var flattenAll = function(data) {
  var result = [];
  var flatten = function(arr) {
    _.forEach(arr, function(a) {
      result.push(a);
      flatten(a.children);
    });
  };
  flatten(data);
  return result;  
};

// Function to search on flattened array
var search = function(flattened, id) {
  var found = _.find(flattened, function(d) { 
              return d.id == id;
            });
  return found;
};

// Function to check if element is found and have children
var hasChildren = function(element) {
  return element && element.children && element.children.length > 0;
}

// Usage, search for id = 6
hasChildren(search(flattenAll(your_data_object), 6))
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sswCQs?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to iterate the nodes recursively and simplify your logic for checking existence by using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const data = [{label:'first',id:1,children:[]},{label:'second',id:2,children:[{label:'third',id:3,children:[{label:'fifth',id:5,children:[]},{label:'sixth',id:6,children:[{label:'seventh',id:7,children:[]}]}]},{label:'fourth',id:4,children:[]}]}];

function * nodes (array) {
  for (const node of array) {
    yield node;
    yield * nodes(node.children);
  }
}

const array = Array.from(nodes(data));

console.log(array.some(node => node.id === 6 && node.children.length > 0));
console.log(array.some(node => node.id === 7 && node.children.length > 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

We now use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for data processing needs like this. It's very powerful once you wrap your head around it. This is how you could solve your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const hasChildren = (e) => e instanceof Object && Array.isArray(e.children) && e.children.length !== 0;
const find = (id, input) => {
  const match = objectScan(['**'], {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'value',
    filterFn: ({ value }) => value.id === id
  })(input);
  return hasChildren(match);
};

const data = [{ label: 'first', id: 1, children: [] }, { label: 'second', id: 2, children: [{ label: 'third', id: 3, children: [{ label: 'fifth', id: 5, children: [] }, { label: 'sixth', id: 6, children: [{ label: 'seventh', id: 7, children: [] }] }] }, { label: 'fourth', id: 4, children: [] }] }];

console.log(find(6, data));
// => true
console.log(find(2, data));
// => true
console.log(find(7, data));
// => false
console.log(find(999, data));
// => false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)